# Large data sets with heavy tails - best fitting strategy

Tags: distributions, density-function, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, circular-statistics

I have relatively large data sets with about 20000 to 25000 data. The data are the orientation angles (0 - 180°) of fibers in a composite material. You can see two example histograms showing the most extreme histograms. The first one has a "nice" bell-shaped distribution, the second one is also bell-shaped but the tails are much more pronounced. The aim is to fit a parametric probability distribution to the data. This pdf will be used later to create a statistically representative model of the composite. Therefore, standard/established pdfs should be used. My numerical fitting strategy was:

1. perform maximum likelihood estimation to determine the characteristic parameters of different pdf functions (normal, t-location scale, logistic, ...).
2. quantifying the fit with the KS-test and determining the best function by comparing the p-value.

Now to the problem:
The p-values of many samples are quite small (10^-8 and smaller). In these cases, the decision criterion "largest p-value" does not seem to be significant. After some research, I would say that the small p-values can be explained by the power of the KS-test on large data sets and the pronounced tails ("outliers").

Change in numerical fitting strategy:
The KS-test does not seem to be appropriate for the data, or rather, the data are not appropriate for the KS test. I am aware that one should not select tests or change data to get the desired result. But I still want to approximate my data with standard parametric pdfs, knowing that the fit is not ideal. I would now replace the second step of the fitting strategy with a comparison of the sum of squared errors (SSE). I calculate the error as the distance between the cdf of my empirical data and the cdf of the fitted function, evaluated for each data point. This is advantageous because all errors are taken into account, not just the largest as in the KS-test. Also, the SSE is in a range between 10^-1 and 10^1, so a comparison between the different types of functions seems to make more sense.

My questions:

- Is this an appropriate/valid strategy?
- If you look at the histograms, you can see some kind of constant baseline. This cannot be represented by the pdfs as they tend towards 0 at the tails. One idea is to split the pdf into a constant and a bell-shaped one. Is this an idea that should be pursued further or is it a "waste of time"?
- Do you have any advice or comments on points I have missed or should approach differently?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two thoughts which aren't really a complete answer. 1 - if you're dealing with angles, you may want to consider a _circular distribution_. 2 - the KS test considers the maximum distance between the reference and empirical distribution. You may, depending on the final application, wish to consider a different goodness of fit test which more considers the overall shape (eg a chi squared variant). It is certainly not wrong to use a KS just be aware there are other options available.